# Sweeper never triggers

Tags: ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following usecase: I have an API and a UI which both modify the same type of object Vehicle. However, when a vehicle is modified from the UI, it must have a Vehicle Identification Number provided, while if it is modified, that number may not yet be known as it has not yet been stamped on the Engine Block (this is clearly a manufactured example).

So my model is:

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :set_ivars
  def set_ivars
    @strict_vid_validation = true
  end 
  validate :vid, length: {maximum: 100, minimum: 30}, presence: true, if: lambda { |o| o.instance_variable_get(:@strict_vid_validation) }
 validate :custom_vid_validator, unless: lambda { |o| o.instance_variable_get(:@strict_vid_validation) }

end
```

Two parent controllers:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_api_filter

  private
    def set_api_filter
      @api = false
    end
end
```

and an `ApiController` that sets `@api` to true

and the following vehicle controller:

```
class VehicleController < ApplicationController

  cache_sweeper VehicleSweeper, only: [:create, :update]

  def create
    @vehicle = Vehicle.new
    @vehicle.update_attributes(params[:vehicle])
  end
end
```

with the following sweeper:

```
class VehicleSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe Vehicle

  def before_validation(vehicle)
    if self.instance_variable_get(:@api)
      vehicle.instance_variable_set(:@strict_vid_validation, false)
    else
      vehicle.instance_variable_set(:@strict_vid_validation, true)
    end
  end
```

And a somewhat similiar `ApiVehicleController`

However, this does not work. Through debugging I have discovered that:

1) The `before_validation` (nor do any other callbacks configured) method in the sweeper never runs

2) The more stringent ui validation is always triggered, this is due to

3) inside the lambda on the if: on the validate, the instance_variable is always true as it is never set through a callback method

Why is this not working? How can I fix it? Is there a different approach I could take if not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the following worked:

```
def my_controller_action
    @vehicle = Vehicle.new
    @vehicle.assign_attributes(params[:vehicle])
    VehicleSweeper.send(:new).pick_a_validation(@vehicle)
    @vehicle.save
end
```

and in the sweeper removing the line

```
observe Vehicle
```

and renaming the `before_validation` method to `pick_a_validation`.

Of course this only works because I wanted to do a `before_validation`. If I wanted to do say an `after_validation` I have no idea how I would have hacked it.

In either case, I would love to hear how this is done without bypassing the callback chain entirely like I did.